# Для чего предназначен "СтандартнаяОбработка"(параметр) в 1С?

Tags: база-данных, 1с

Прошу помочь. Для чего предназначен "СтандартнаяОбработка" в 1С (простыми словами)?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Этот параметр "пробрасывается" в вызываемые процедуры; Процедура может проверить его, и если он = Ложь пропустить выполнение своего кода;

Answer (score 0):

Используется для переопределения действий платформы.
Если он установлен в "Истина", тогда платформа не будет принимать действий, которые в ней заложены для обработки того или иного события. И Вы можете написать свой код для обработки прикладной логики.